# Scroll Bars have vanished after adding a Google Map to a page - how do I get them back

Tags: html, scroll, scrollbar

I have just been implementing a google map, that pulls data from the yelp API. All fine, apart from I've noticed that the scroll bars on the page have dissappeared. Problem exists in FF and IE on Mac and PC.

Take a look - http://bhx-birmingham-airport.co.uk/pages/hotels.php

What do I need to do to get them back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently in your hotels.php page there is a css rule:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden; /* <-- this is causing the problem! */
}
```

Change it and remove the `overflow:hidden` or if you can't do that (for example if google's code injects that style in there) then add another rule in your css file:

```
body {
    overflow:auto !important;
}
```